# ReplayKit, status bar won't go away after watching preview

Tags: ios, replaykit

My app has status bar hidden at all times.

Except when viewing a recorded preview, the status bar comes up when watching the preview in the preview controller, but it does not go away when the preview controller is dismissed. I've double checked that `prefersStatusBarHidden` returns YES for the controller I am using. I really need to keep the status bar hidden at all times.

- `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];` does not help. I tried calling this in the handler `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.
- `[self.viewController setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];` does not help either. I tried calling this in the handler `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`.

I noticed that the status bar seems to go away properly if user goes to home screen and back. That's not enough for a fix however.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. The delegates of ReplayKit need to do UI things on the main thread, that includes dismissing the preview controller specifically. When I fixed that, the status bar trouble went away.

Answer (score 0):

Seems weird not working in iOS 9.0.2 , but work in other system version?

```
- (void)previewControllerDidFinish:
(RPPreviewViewController*)previewController
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (previewController != nil)
        {
            [previewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: 
nil];
        }
    });
}
```

Setting **View controller-based status bar appearance** in **info.plist** to **YES** and return **YES** of **prefersStatusBarHidden** method in viewController work for me

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

and this site may help: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/19626